# Uncaught ReferenceError: module is not defined at push.js

Tags: phonegap-plugins, phonegap, push.js

I am developing an Android App using Phonegap and trying to add the Push Notification. 
I already added the plugin successfully using "phonegap plugin add phonegap-plugin-push". Config.xml was also updated and i can see the version of push plugin as 2.2.3.
Note: i created the project using the push-template. Cordova.js is also coded in index.html.

When i try to view my application on google browser. I get these errors.

- Uncaught ReferenceError: module is not defined
  at push.js:330
- Uncaught TypeError: PushNotification.init is not a function.

I am not allowed yet to post pictures so here's the link for the section which is having an issue.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ezw6U.png

I've been trying to fix this. Read all related problem on github and stackoverflow but to no avail.

These are the versions i'm using.

- cordova 9.0.0
- phonegap 8.2.2

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

The browser will give you this error if you are previewing your app using the index.html from the root folder of your application.

It should be compiled first to a specific platform so you can preview the app from the compiled files. This is the path in case of Android: **platforms\android\app\src\main\assets\www**

Comment: However i get the same fault after running on android.